# The ads for Stack Overflow jobs are misleading

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I just saw this ad on SuperUser:

[image]

And it directed me to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/why-jobs?utm_source=superuser.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=candidates-add-cv&utm_content=sb-launch-yourself

This is *not* the first  ad I have seen that looks like an ad for Stack Overflow, but misleadingly gets me to the jobs page (the other was a blue banner ad of which I did not screenshot)

Can it be updated so that the ad actually describes what it is pointing to instead of pointing to something (seemingly) different?

### Update

Here are a few others I just found on refresh:

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]

(the "blue" one)

[image: Blue Example]

Comment: You call it *misleading* but the marketing department calls this *success* ...

Comment: But I thought I was clicking on an ad for StackOverflow in general.... They make no sense....

Comment: Might be nice if it said "Jobs on Stack Overflow" or something similar.

Comment: It *did* take you to SO: "it directed me to http://stackoverflow.com/jobs..." and the "launch *yourself*" tagline is not SO's motto or anything.

Comment: Is it? Where does it say that is the StackOverflow motto (aside from that ad)?

Comment: The only ad I find odd is the blue one. Assuming it does not take you to http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I don't think they are meant to be community-ads. The Jobs team paid big bucks to get their ads on the site ...

Comment: yeah, agree that it should be clearer that we're sending you to Jobs. When Jobs lived on a separate site, these ads contained the logo, "Stack Overflow Careers," which (I think) made the destination/message clearer. We haven't updated the ad designs for the Jobs-on-Stack Overflow world, though. Thanks for the heads up, and will put the request in.

Comment: Thank you so much @Donna -- Can you add that as an answer? :-)

Comment: @rene Yet another example of why so many developers seem to instinctively consider the marketing department "the enemy"

Comment: At first I thought the ad was showing a sword poking through the clouds

Comment: @MasonWheeler rene was joking ... I hope.

Comment: I could only assume that _launch yourself_ is a way of saying- _if you use StackOverflow Jobs you will be launching yourself to a higher level_ (read: we will give you a job better than your current one). However, I agree with @Donna, it should be clearer.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Yeah, agree that it should be clearer that we're sending you to Jobs. When Jobs lived on a separate site, these ads contained the logo, "Stack Overflow Careers," which (I think) made the destination/message clearer. We haven't updated the ad designs for the Jobs-on-Stack Overflow world, though. Thanks for the heads up, and will put the request in.

**Update**: Marketing & Ad teams are aware of this issue and will take it from here :)

Comment: I think Stack Overflow Careers would still be a good name, even if it's not a separate domain to start with. At least it makes it reasonably clear what it's about, although it could be about jobs with SO (or SE) as well.

Comment: Ads are all confusing and that's how it works. People click ads link thinking something different and land into somewhere else. Moment you make it straight saying *stackoverflow careers*  the number of hits may drop down ...

Comment: if ads were not confusing or flat out lying no one would click on them

Comment: I don't know why so many people keep saying that the purpose of ads is to trick you. Certainly that is the motivation behind *some* ads, but there are legitimate ads that serve to...well, *advertise*. You know, inform people about things they didn't previously know about in a non-disingenuous way. If the product is good, or the service stands on its own merit, fraudulent advertising is not necessary. The fact that a product/service is advertised fraudulently is a good sign to me and many other informed consumers that it should be ignored.

Answer (score -3):

Isn't that the whole point of advertisements? To mislead you a bit? To reach out to that inner desire? To light your fire?

I'm not saying this is on purpose or how it was meant to be. It is a personal thing how you perceive an ad. I doubt that feeling misled is a great emotion to have when you click on a ad, no matter what.

The ads that are shown are *normal* ads, not community-ads. The Jobs team "pays" for impressions and they run several variants to see which one attracts more people. I don't think the community has much to say about the quality or intentions of ads. That is the responsibility of the advertiser. Only if it is bad taste which isn't the case here.

That you didn't proceed to the checkout to buy a job is probably noted already. If too many users do that, they probably would change stuff. Either the ad, so they attract the correct category of customers, or the page you land on, to make sure you keep shopping.

Wouldn't you want that all advertisers have a Meta site to gather direct feedback on their ads ... so they can be improved.

Comment: To be clear, the misleading nature of these ads was an oversight, not a strategy to gain clicks.

Comment: Oh, I'm not blaming or shaming anyone @Donna that is not my point.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was your intent, but _proceed to the checkout to buy a job_ made me laugh, at least.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom If I can make one person smile I'm happy ... have a wonderful day ...

Comment: Saying there are '1000 jobs for you' while there are actually just 300 that fit my profile, that's the kind of misleading you might expect from such an advert. Clickbait that suggests it to be about something else is not proper. Just a small step further and you got those ads looking like a  download button on sites like SourceForge. Great success according to the clickcounters... I'm glad with @Donna's explanation that this is not the intention for SO.

Comment: You don't think the community has anything to say about quality or intentions of ads? That's preposterous. StackOverflow is unique in that it can only survive by the community *wanting to be here*. You'd better believe their opinions are important. If the community is alienated, the whole thing will die.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @ErikE. I don't see the relation between the community and the ads being served. I'm here for the Q/A. I rather leave the assessment of the effectiveness of a campaign to the paid professionals but I understand now that we all need to have a say in that. So be it.

Comment: I will agree with @rene. Ads are always made like that so that it gets more hit. Go and make a survey for almost every such ads banner.

Comment: It's a damn shame this is downvoted so much when it's right.

Comment: yes @billrichards. It is the bitter truth and some refuse to accept it. No offense to anyone in particular.

Comment: lemme upvote it ( though it is only a drop of sweet water in the negativity sea :D)