# Why my meta answer was deleted

Tags: discussion, support, meta, deleted-answers

I gave a answer for [Do we really need these Software Engineering related tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355013/do-we-really-need-these-software-engineering-related-tags). It was deleted by four users delete vote.

I think you can read the answer if you have 10k rep. For others I repeat the answer.

> Yes, It is really need because even those are off-topic we can learn
>   something form them. :-)

Below my answer I saw follwing notice.

> Why was your post deleted? See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

So answers are deleted because of following reasons.

- commentary on the question or other answers
- asking another, different question
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
- exact duplicates of other answers
- barely more than a link to an external site
- not even a partial answer to the actual question

But I don't see any of reasons belong to my answer. Yes, all community may disagree with what I said in that answer. But it is a answer for the question. If community disagree with the answer they can down vote.

So why was my answer deleted?

Comment: Part of me wants to get mad that people are using their delete votes to silence others' opinions, and part of me wants to give them the benefit of the doubt that maybe they just don't think it's worth keeping an unsubstantiated one-liner opinion around when it's overwhelmingly unpopular.

Comment: It was almost certainly deleted because those community members didn't think that it was worth keeping something so clearly unpopular, and unsubstantiated. It was a one-liner opinion without motivation.

Comment: Maybe they felt your answer was more of a comment.

Comment: They probably deleted it because they thought it was a joke, and [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). It certainly does not look like a serious answer.

Comment: Also, the English in your one-liner is manhandled to the point where it is hard to tell what you even meant.

Answer (score 13):

Nothing in the question stands out as being funny or a joke, nor was it posted on Friday. The OP has done their extensive research and compiled a list and reasoning for the handling of a bunch of tags. They may expect their effort is discussed in the same way.

Your joke, which is only funny if you have my sense of humor, doesn't come near to even address in anyway the concerns expressed by the OP. Some might even say it is rude to try to get away with such a cheap joke. Deletion of your answer is in order as it has no value for future visitors, let alone the OP.

We do hate fun so if you are trying to be funny, carefully select your target posts.

And as the suggestion is to [leave a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327437/the-ads-for-stack-overflow-jobs-are-misleading/327440#comment364325_327437) but don't be surprised if the [answers that extends on that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327440/578411) still falls flat. Use chat as a somewhat safe practice ground.

Comment: Or just leave a comment. We hate fun in comments a bit less (at least on Meta).

Comment: @Cody and be sure to add something about waffles and unicorns and it'll probably even get upvotes!

Comment: @CodyGray **Question** : Do we really need these Software Engineering related tags? -- **Answer** : Yes, It is really need because even those are off-topic we can learn something form them. :-) .............. What is the funny part of my answer? I directly answer the question with my opinion.... In simply said who used this sites are programmers.  I thought they cn learn something from those tags also because most of programmers are works with SD methods like agile...

Comment: @DonkeyKing perhaps if you'd elaborated about *what* could be learned along with examples... After someone's asked a thoughtful and researched post, a vague "we can learn something from them" isn't really saying that much...

Comment: Programmers also eat food. And lots of programmers I know drink beer. Should we also allow, "What is the best brew of beer?" questions? No, [there are rules for what is and is not on-topic for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That your answer completely ignored those was why it seemed like a joke to me. Also the smiley face. @donkey

Comment: @JonClements It may be true, but my mother language is not English...... I never mean fun in that answer

Comment: In that case you have to look up what **:-)** means. It isn't common interpunction to end a sentence. It carries much more meaning. ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray I think iwhat you said is valid only if the question tags are something like cooking or foods. But it is about software engineering  related tags.

Answer (score 11):

Imagine that I answered this question with the following and nothing else

> Because it wasn't useful :-)

Would you consider that an answer to your question? I'd expect such an answer to be downvoted and probably even deleted. Why?

1. It's a comment. A one-line zinger that plays to an audience. It deserves a rimshot (or [sting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_(percussion)), as Wikipedia calls it)
2. It doesn't really answer the question (which is the cardinal sin on SO)

So your answer was

> Yes, It is really need because even those are off-topic we can learn something form them. :-)

To which my first response is

> What can we learn from them?

Note that I'm giving you **reasons** why your answer was deleted, which is what you wanted (or you wouldn't have posted this). You need to do the same for your fellow user, otherwise your responses become noise in otherwise serious discussions.

Comment: +1 if the first revision of this answer would have been *Because it wasn't useful :-)*. I call it a missed opportunity...

Comment: @rene But that edit wouldn't have been useful ;-)